# What would be a CharacterController equivalent for OnCollisionStay in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I changed my character's collider from box collider to character controller. However, some scripts didn't work. Since my camera switching code worked when changing to OnTriggerEnter, I tried to write a OnTriggerStay but that didn't work.

Code:

```cs
    void OnCollisionStay(Collision  col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Interact") && InteractivityState == false) 
            {
                InteractivityState = true;
                CameraChange.SetActive(true);
                CameraRevert.SetActive(false);
                ExamineSound.Play();
                StartCoroutine(ShowText());
                
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ShowText()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ReplacementText.Length + 1; i++)
        {
            DescriptionText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            CurrentText = ReplacementText.Substring(0,i);
            DescriptionText.text = CurrentText;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (TextDelay);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Interact") && InteractivityState == true)
        {
            InteractivityState = false;
            DescriptionText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            StopCoroutine(ShowText());
            CameraChange.SetActive(false);
            CameraRevert.SetActive(true);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I need more information to know what is wrong, can you share pictures of Unity Editor?

Answer (score 0):

If I need to guess, I think it should be that the character controller does not have a rigidbody attached, so any of those methods would be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a rigidbody component on your character just try this - https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html